# Broken graphics after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, ubuntu-mate, compositing

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu MATE 20.04 (from version 18) and my graphics are broken. I think it might be the composer's fault, since I saw Compton was uninstalled. How could I fix this?

Screenshot of my desktop after upgrading:

[image: Failed to download repository information - Check your internet connection]

The output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` is the following:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/-ATI] Picasso (rev c4) 
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Picasso
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was suspecting, the compositing windows manager was the culprit. I disabled it in Window Preferences> General and everything now works flawlessly.